# Linear Algebra: Ax=b. Finding b, given x and A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

Define the $n$ x $n$ array $(a_{ij})$ by $a_{ij}$=$-1$+$2 \mbox{max}(i,j)$. Set up array $b_i$ in such a way that the solution of the system $Ax=b$ is $x_i$ =$1$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$.

My attempt: I tried looking at this in concrete cases to find a pattern.  Note the answer was given to be $b_i=n^2+2(i-1)$.  I just have no idea how to derive this for generally.

I consider $n=3$. And get A:You have for example $\begin{bmatrix}1&3&5\\3&3&5\\5&5&5\end{bmatrix}\circ \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}9\\11\\15\end{bmatrix}$.

However, based on the answer given, it should be:\begin{bmatrix}9\\11\\13\end{bmatrix}.

Thus, I'm having 2 problems:
1. Is the answer given, wrong, or am I making a mistake that I am not seeing?
2. How was the answer derived, that is how was a formula obtained for $b_i$?
Thank you.

Comment: $b_n=n(-1+2n)$ is the correct formula for for $b_n$

Comment: But n represents the size of the matrix. So if A=4 x 4, n=4 We would then need b1, b2, b3, b4.  Shouldn't b depend on both i and n?

Comment: It does I'm just saying the correct equation for the last position is that

Comment: $5+5+5=15$, not $13$. The "answers in the back of the book" are generally put in as an afterthought, and are often inaccurate or just plain wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is what I figured.  That being said, is it even possible to come up with a general formula for bi.  Or would this be too difficult?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The way I see it, $bi=n^2$, $b_{i+1}=b_{i}+2$ ; $b_{i+2}=b_{i+1}+4$ etc.  But, I'm not sure how to write this in a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$b_i = -n + 2 \sum max(i,j) = -n + 2\sum_{j \le i} max(i,j) + 2\sum_{j >i} max(i,j)$

$= -n + 2\sum_{j \le i}i + 2\sum_{j=i+1}^nj = -n + 2[i^2 + \frac {n(n+1) - i(i+1)}2] = n^2 + i^2-i $

Comment: Hi, @LordKK so should the answer be [9,11,13] for what I illustrated or should it be [9,11,15]

Comment: But then this gives me $b_3=6$, which I don't think is correct?

Comment: if i=3, and n=3, your formula gives $b_3$=$6$, which I don't think is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't take factor of 2 into account. I will edit.

Comment: I think now, it is giving the value 15 for i=n=3

Comment: Great I think this is exactly correct.  Thanks